# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. react-hook-form default values throwing errors, when passing the optional values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm trying to pass a defaultValues inside the below constraint but it's throwing the error like below,

What went wrong with this initilization, Thanks in advance

The constraint

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isSubmitting } } = useForm<NoteInput>({
         defaultValues:{
                title: noteToEdit?.title || "",
                text: noteToEdit?.text || "",
            }
         });
```

The error

```
./src/components/AddEditNoteDialogProps.tsx 15:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   var _useForm = useForm({
|       defaultValues: {
>         title: noteToEdit?.title || "",
|         text: noteToEdit?.text || ""
|       }
```

Full code

```
import { Button, Form, Modal, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";
import { Note } from "../models/note";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { NoteInput } from "../network/notes_api";
import * as NotesApi from "../network/notes_api";

interface AddEditNoteDialogProps {
    noteToEdit?:Note,
    onDismiss: () => void,
    onNoteSaved: (note: Note) => void,
}

const AlertEditDialogNote = ({ noteToEdit,onDismiss, onNoteSaved }: AddEditNoteDialogProps) => {

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isSubmitting } } = useForm<NoteInput>({
         defaultValues:{
                title: noteToEdit?.title || "", // the reason for the throwing an error
                text: noteToEdit?.text || "", //
            }
         });

    async function onSubmit(input: NoteInput) {
        try {

            let noteResponse:Note;
            if(noteToEdit){
                noteResponse=await NotesApi.updateNote(noteToEdit._id,input)
            }else{
                noteResponse = await NotesApi.createNote(input);
            }
            onNoteSaved(noteResponse);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <Modal show onHide={onDismiss}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title> 
                    { noteToEdit ? "Edit note" : "Add note" }
                </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Form id="addEditNoteform" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Label> Title </Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Title"
                            isInvalid={!!errors.title}
                            {...register("title", { required: "Required" })}
                        />
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                            {/* {errors.title?.message} */}
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Label> Text </Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            as="textarea"
                            rows={5}
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Text"
                            {...register("text")}
                        />

                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button type="submit" form="addEditNoteform" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                    save
                </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
    );
}

export default AlertEditDialogNote;
```

Comment: what version of **react-scripts** you are using ?

Comment: react-script - 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `react-scripts` library is   out-of-date. The current version is **5.0.1** . just **upgrade your react-script** . it will fix the error

Comment: Thanks a lot, monium, i used this command to upgrade, `npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@5.0.1`

Comment: because of you, i can able to continue, thanks again, love from srilanka

Comment: that's cool thanks love from morocco lol . I suppose you were using **create-react-app** it sometimes install different **react-script** version automatically